# Show a pretty character table in Linux shell console

Tags: linux, shell, formatting, echo

I want to show a text menu, and let the user choice, for example a table similar like below:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃     WIFI Tools Menu      ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ 1. Create virtual WLAN   ┃
┃ 2. Start virtual WLAN    ┃
┃ 3. Stop virtual WLAN     ┃
┃ 4. View WLAN connections ┃
┃ 5. Change WLAN password  ┃
┃ 6. Share Connection(ICS) ┃
┃ 7. Exit                  ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

The table show pretty good for Windows batch, even the Linux shell console use monospaced font, but the output still is ugly.

I used the "select" in shell script before, but looks ugly, also the dialog + menu is another solution, but it don't keep the same experience for end-user, my script need to do a lot of tasks, I don't want to popup a dialog.

How can a show the above table with pretty formatting?

Windows Menu:

[image: Windows Result]

Linux Menu:

[image: Linux Result]

Comment: The Linux console definitely uses a mono spaced font.

Comment: I haven't come across any distributions that *doesn't* default to a monospaced font in any terminal emulator application. What distribution and terminal emulator application are you using?

Comment: It's not a programming question, it's a deployment question.

Comment: Sorry, I add some screen capture now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty clear from your screenshots your problem is on windows, not linux: your horizontal lines do not actually join and the gaps do not map to the letter splits in your text. You've managed to find a "monospace" font where horizontal line is two-characters-wide (why am I even surprised, clean line drawing requires the box drawing unicode block and windows+console+utf-8 is definitely an unholy mix)

On Linux where monospace actually means monospace your horizontal lines are twice as short as a result.

If you want a correct app you need to take Linux as reference and find whatever bug you have on windows, not workaround the windows bug and expect Linux to behave the same.

Comment: Very interesting. When I change the gedit font as "AR PL ukai HK",, the table looks great! Anyway, when I double the symbol "━", the table can show correct under Linux. It works for me. Thanks, nim! If I double the "━", that line is double length of other lines, so I consider Linux have some problem to show the OEM tabular chars, otherwise these lines length should be the same value!

Comment: Linux does not have any problem displaying the box drawing unicode block, if your length routine thinks the line is twice as long that means it is hopelessly confused (it's probably counting bytes and not characters byte ≠ character in every existing unicode encoding). Try drawing a single horizontal line (U+2500) if it's not the same width as a single letter the code is wrong period. "AR PL ukai HK" is not a monospace font, and the latest thing you want to dabble with is a CJK font when your unicode processing is shaky.

Comment: Dear nim, many thanks for you comments. You're right. Under Linux, the length is same char length.